# Dynamic Programming on Binary Tree: Maximize data transmitted with limited edge capacity

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a network of a binary tree of nodes with edge capacities c_e. There are data at the leaf nodes and each has data size s_v. L_e is the set of all leaves in the subtree below edge e. Our aim is to find subset S of leaves such that the number of data size transmitted to the root r is maximized, but for all the edges that the data passes through the capacity constraint must hold. It is assumed that c_e and s_v are non negative integers and let m be their maximum. Using dynamic programming on trees it should run in O(nm^2) time.

I have working on this for hours but haven't really come up woth a working solution. Any hints would be appreciated.

**edit:**
The data must be transmitted as a whole or not at all. for example if a leaf has 10 the algorithm can only take 10 or 0 at all.

for example,

```
v4=1, v5=3, v6=2, v7=2. 
e1=(v1,r), e2=(v2,v1) and e3=(v3,v1) and so on. 
assume that the capacity for e4, e5,e6 and e7 satisfied. But c1=5, c2=3 and c3=4
```

if we focused on finding the maximum of each subtree, we will end up taking v5 and v6+v7 which is not optimal. how to make dynamic programming rule that can tackle this problem and find the correct optimal solution?

Comment: Maybe an overkill, but could be a Max-flow problem with multiple sources.

Comment: Is this an all-or-nothing choice? In other words, if a leaf has size 10, is it allowed to send 7 from that leaf to the root?

Comment: I somehow doubt there exists an efficient solution. It seems closely related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: yes @user3386109, it is an all-or-nothing choice. if the leaf has size 10, it is only allowed to take 10 or not at all, that's why this is not a max flow problem. I will edit the question for this information.

Comment: Assuming all edges have unlimited capacity, except those edges leading to the root, you will have to find the combination of the leaves in the left half of the tree which leads to the number closest to the capacity of the left edge to the root (same for the right edge and right half of the tree). There is no efficient solution for that. In other words dynamic programming doesn't seem to work for this problem.

Comment: @maraca I have improved my question for more requirement. It is stated by the problem that the running time for this algorithm should run in O(nm^2) time using DP on trees.

Comment: Based on the running time, I'd say that you want an NxM table that answers the question, "Given capacity `c` to the parent node, what is the maximum data that can be sent from the current node (for all `c` in the range 0 to `m`)?"

Comment: You need to find the maximum transmittable amount of data only or you need to find the subset of leaf nodes which sums up to that number too?

Comment: @maraca just finding the subset of leaf nodes is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the dynamic programming solution for subset sum...

For each node, calculate the set of attainable sums for subsets of the leaves, and for each attainable sum, remember the last contributing child and the previous sum.  You can use this information to reconstruct the set that produces the sum.

While doing a postorder traversal of the tree, you can calculate this set for each node using only the information on its children.

When you get to the root, pick the maximum attainable sum and reconstruct the leaves that produce it.

Comment: are you saying that we are making the set of attainable sums while traversing the nodes using postorder traversal? and what do you mean by attainable sums? is it all possible sums which satisfy the edge capacity?

Comment: By "attainable sums" I mean the possible total amounts of data that could be made to pass up through that node.  You only need to consider totals that are <= the node's parent edge capacity.  At v3, for example, the attainable sums are 2 and 4